# Inference of the generic function argument

Tags: typescript, generics

For example, I have the following function that returns the same type that accepts as the first argument:

```
function example<T>(parameter: (data:T) => T) {
    return null;
}
```

But when I try to use the function I see `data` is `unknown` instead of `string`:

```
example((data) => {
    return "test"
})
```

How to solve this issue?

Comment: `example<string>(...)`?

Comment: @tromgy, I want to preserve types inference. The type can be a far more complicated.

Comment: Seems like a current design limitation and https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/47599 is a suggestion to improve it. On mobile now, might have more to say when I can research on a real computer

Comment: The TS function `data => "test"` is *context sensitive*; the type of `data` has not been annotated. The compiler defers inference on such functions until after generic type parameters have been inferred, and by then it's too late (without the callback, there's nothing from which to infer `T`). You want the compiler to notice that the callback returns `string` independently of the type parameter.  That's what ms/TS#47599 asks for. For now you can only either specify `T` manually, or annotate `data` manually, forcing you to write out a type you want inferred. Shall I write this up as an answer?

Comment: @jcalz, thank you. I suppose it's the sad answer, but the right one.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally understanding your purpose but i think that my example should help you understand:

```
function example<T>(par:T,parameter: (data:T) => T):T {
    return parameter(par);
}

let myexample = example("test",(data) => {return data+ Date.now()});
console.log(myexample);
```

You are declaring a function "example" that has a callback of generic type "T" inside but you didn't use this callback. If you don't use it there is nothing that can help define wich kind of type you are using.

The "Generics" documentation helped me: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-types)